# Image batch processing crop empty alpha channel of .pngs in imagemagick or similar tools

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, batch-processing

I have a bunch of PNG images of the same overall size but with different smaller 'things' in it. I want to crop these images so that all 'unused' alpha channel space is discarded and the new images are of smaller size.

[An example what I want to happen. Green is the alpha channel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJIBt.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [-trim](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim). So, for a single image:

```
magick input.png -trim +repage result.png
```

For lots of images, make a backup first and try on a copy:

```
magick mogrify -trim +repage *.png
```